How to handle timer logic in node.js backend
I am trying to write a trivia game, where users answer questions and each question has a 20 second timer. Assuming there is an http endpoint to serve a question that a client can initiate, what's the best way to return a response to the client, then in the background run a 20 second timer that, once done, checks if all players have submitted an answer or not? Should a worker thread be used for this in node.js or is there a simpler approach?
